# Ignoring lines within a doxygen comment block

Tags: documentation, comments, fortran, doxygen

Is it possible to include content within a doxygen comment block that will be ignored by doxygen? In order words, can we have comments within a doxygen comment block?

**Background:**

We're converting the in-code comments for a Fortran project to a doxygen-parseable format, however the project requires that the content within the in-code comments be delineated by *horizontal lines*. For example:

```
!> @brief Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
!! ---------------------------------------------------------------------
!!
!! @param[in] p1  Description of p1
!! @param[in] p2  Description of p2
!! ---------------------------------------------------------------------
!!
!! More content here ....
!! ---------------------------------------------------------------------
!!
!! More content for another section
!! ---------------------------------------------------------------------
subroutine do_something(p1, p2)
  ! .... the code ...
end subroutine do_something
```

Is there a command/syntax I can prefix those lines with so that doxygen will ignore them? Hopefully, one that is unobtrusive and does not affect the readability of the comments.

I am aware of the [`INPUT_FILTER`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_input_filter) settings which one can use to chain in a preprocessing script, but the ideal solution would be one that does not depend on additional scripts/tools.

*P.S. I'm well aware that many would think those horizontal lines unnecessary and/or distracting. However, it is a requirement decreed by the paymaster and is not something that I am at the liberty to change.*

Comment: AFAIK you can just start those lines with a single `!`. That would probably be the easiest solution. As a side note, comments which *preceed* the object they are documenting normally start with `!>`, not `!<`.

Comment: That did come to mind but I was cautious of it spitting the block up (I should really test this when I'm back at work on Monday). As for the `!<` that was a typo. My bad.

Comment: It turns out that I was mistaken, you will have to proceed each subsequent block of content with `!>`. So you could have the horizontal lines start with a single `!` and the following line start with a `!>`. However, the more quirks like this you have to remember the less chance there is that your project will be documented correctly and consistently. It seems that [DRH](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12328195/623518)'s solution is the most straightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could leverage Doxygen's alias syntax to ignore the line, however it will require that the line be prefixed and suffixed with additional characters. For example, if you defined an alias like:

```
ALIASES                = I{1}=""
```

You could use the alias in your comment to hide the horizontal breaks from doxygen:

```
!> @brief Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
!! @I{-----------------------------------------------------------------}
!!
!! @param[in] p1  Description of p1
!! @param[in] p2  Description of p2
!! @I{-----------------------------------------------------------------}
!!
!! More content here ....
!! @I{-----------------------------------------------------------------}
!!
!! More content for another section
!! @I{-----------------------------------------------------------------}
subroutine do_something(p1, p2)
  ! .... the code ...
end subroutine do_something
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a go when I'm back at my desk. I'll get back to you once I've tried it.

Comment: Many thanks. That works. Not quite as seamless as I'd like it to be, but it certainly answers the question as I've posted it i.e. *"how to including content that is ignored by doxygen"*.

Comment: FYI, in the end I've [decided to use HTML comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320377/ignoring-lines-within-a-doxygen-comment-block/12352989#12352989).

Answer (score 6):

Doxygen supports some [HTML commands](http://www.star.bnl.gov/public/comp/sofi/doxygen/htmlcmds.html) including HTML comments. This solution has the benefit of not requiring any modifications to the Doxyfile and marginally less distracting than `@I{ ---- }`.

```
!> @brief Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
!! <!----------------------------------------------------------------->
!!
!! @param[in] p1  Description of p1
!! @param[in] p2  Description of p2
!! <!----------------------------------------------------------------->
!!
!! More content here ....
!! <!----------------------------------------------------------------->
!!
!! More content for another section
!! <!----------------------------------------------------------------->
subroutine do_something(p1, p2)
  ! .... the code ...
end subroutine do_something
```

---

<sup>*For the record, this is the solution which I eventually settled on. However, I've accepted [DRH's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320377/ignoring-lines-within-a-doxygen-comment-block/12328287#12328287) as it provides a more generic solution to "enabling comments within a doxygen block".*</sup>

Answer (score 4):

If you have flexibility in which character is used for the horizontal line, you can continue to repeat the comment character, and doxygen will ignore it. Something like:

```
!> @brief Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!
!! @param[in] p1  Description of p1
!! @param[in] p2  Description of p2
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!
!! More content here ....
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!
!! More content for another section
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
subroutine do_something(p1, p2)
  ! .... the code ...
end subroutine do_something
```

Comment: This works too, and has the benefit of not requiring additional entries in Doxyfile, but oh my eyes. Arguably more distracting the then horizontal lines.

Answer (score -1):

You could write a simple filter to remove those lines.  In perl, it might look like this:

```
while (<>)
{
    if (m/^!! -{3,}/)
    {
        print "!!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        print;
    }
}
```

Then configure `INPUT_FILTER` in your `Doxyfile` to reference this script:

```
INPUT_FILTER = path/to/my/perl/script
```

Comment: Did you try your solution? When I interpret the perl script correctly it removes the lines starting with !! followed by a space and a minimum of 3 minus signs. Result is that not all documentation is shown anymore.