# How to make Doxygen to ignore some commands?

Tags: doxygen

Having this example header file:

```
/**
 * @brief Some func.
 * 
 * @param a 
 * @param b 
 * @return int 
 * @note Some note
 */
int some_func(int a, int b);
```

How can I tell Doxygen to ignore the `@note` (or any other) commands when generating documentation?

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Which other commands do you mean? For `\note` you you could have a look at the commands like `\if` and `\internal` and at the possibility of `ALIASSES = note=\noop`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment because of my rep.
Here is the solution to ignore lines

[Ignoring lines within a doxygen comment block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320377/ignoring-lines-within-a-doxygen-comment-block)

have a look if it applies to your case

Comment: Strange that you cannot comment as you already gained the commenter badge, it looks to me that your reputation is also large enough

Comment: I got it from commenting to myself :D it starts at 50 :(

Comment: Also I have a question that no one has answered and I want to put a bounty on it, need 50 I think

Comment: now I can comment